# ArUco Markers Distance Estimation Accuracy Difference

Tags: python, opencv, python3, marker, libopencv

The distance estimated *(in cm: Because input size of ArUco Markers in cm too)* using the code line after importing math module:

`numpy.sqrt(tvecs[0][0][0]**2 + tvecs[0][0][1]**2 + tvecs[0][0][2]**2)`
where `tvecs` represent the translation vectors of the ArUco Marker obtained using the OpenCV Function in Python:

`cv.estimateSinglePosemarkers(mtx, dst, .. )`
alongside `rvecs(Rotation Vectors)` obtained using `Camera Matrix(mtx)` and `Distortion Coefficent(dst)` in turn obtained by performing Camera Calibration *(using a piece of code and a bunch of images of a checkerboard held at different angles)*

In contrast, the distance estimated (in cm) using the code line after importing math module:

`math.sqrt(tvecs[0][0][0]**2 + tvecs[0][0][1]**2 + tvecs[0][0][2]**2)`
is pretty accurate(<<10%) at larger distances.

Has anybody run into this before? If so, why does using a different library make such a huge difference?